# How to disable magento 2 extension in store view (multistore)

Tags: magento2, module, extensions, multistore

I have an extension called **Amasty - Xnotif (Out of Stock Notification)**, but for some reason, this extension refuses to be disabled from my store view even when I disable it from the settings.

*So the big questions is, how do I disable this extension from my Store view.*

Other information:

- Disabled in **STORES** -> **CONFIGURATION** -> **ADVANCED** -> **ADMIN**.
- When disabled from the list it disappears from **CONFIGURATION** -> **Amasty EXTENTIONS**, but is still visible on products that don't have stock.
- Magento 2 installation has two stores, so its a multistore and I wish to disable this extension only on one of the stores.
- Cache is not in use.
- I have cleared browser cache.
- Iv run **setup:upgrade** and **setup:static-content** just to be sure everything is updated.

Answer (score 1):

`Disabled in STORES -> CONFIGURATION -> ADVANCED -> ADMIN` does not disable an extension. That is supposed to disable output but it doesn't do what people think it does.

In looking at the screenshots on the extension page, it seems that the `Hide Stock Alert Block` attribute is global so that won't help much if you share the products between the two stores.

One option that will probably work is the config setting `Allow Subscription for Selected Groups`. That option can be set on a per-store basis. Create a customer group with the intention of the group remaining empty (or use Wholesaler or Retailer) and then select that group to be the only group permitted to subscribe, just for the specific store view.

Comment: Seems this one is a bit tricky since the extension affects all stores installed. I need to check in to this more deeply and try to figure a more elegant way to handle it since its still something that is wished to be used on the other store and doing it your way would probably affect the other store as well. Probably going to need some custom coding to get it sorted.

Comment: For the option I recommend, the one that allows a specific subscription group, before you select the groups that are allowed to subscribe, you must select the correct store from store scope dropdown at the top of the page.

Comment: Another option is to use layout xml to remove the block only for the specific store.

Comment: I just came up with the same idea. Trying it out at the moment.

Comment: Any luck with either idea?

Comment: I havent been able to figure this one out yet. since adding <referenceBlock name="amxnotif-block" remove="true"/> to default.xml in the theme files doesn't seem to work as intended. The extension still gets loaded and applied on the page. It could be that I need to hide it through CSS as a last resort.

Answer (score 0):

> Disabled in STORES -> CONFIGURATION -> ADVANCED -> ADMIN.

First, disable from the section, it does not mean that extension will load not load at your store view. Disable from here means th**at extension does not give Block output**.

But another feature of the extension **like the plugin, Class rewrite and observer** will run.

Regarding

> When disabled from the list it disappears from CONFIGURATION -> Amasty
>   EXTENTIONS, but is still visible on products that don't have stock.

Some extension **provide has put some business stop there feature run on the store view** . I have seen that they have put a  simple condition of that setting check on  **plugin, Class rewrite and observer classes**.
Like an observer

```
<?php
nameSpace {YourName}
class {ObserverClass}
{
    public function myObservermethod($Observer)
    {
        if({SystemSetting is enable})
        {
         // run busniness logic 
            }       
    }
}
```

Moral of that Magento default not able to stop there own feature on store view label. **Enable/disabled** pLugin, di class, observer are Global based.

But Running of the business logic on that class totally depends on yours.
Add there you can add settings like Amasty.

Comment: is there a way to make a module run for a specific website, in a multi-website setup of magento?